# Updating user location using iPhone GPS without internet

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, geolocation

I need to get user location and fetch latitude and longitude of even when there is no internet available.

Right now i have implemented CoreLocation methods:-

```
    -(void)updatestart
    {
        // Current location
        _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
        _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        _locationManager.delegate = self;
        [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

    [_locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    NSLog(@"%f",_locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude);
    NSLog(@"%f",_locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

and i am getting the location updates but this only works if we have internet connection.

I guess using iPhone GPS we can fetch the location even without internet.

Any idea of how to implement that??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably get the location if you go under clear sky because then your GPS receiver access the GPS directly and you dont need to have any internet. But if you under any roof then GPS receiver cant access GPS directly then it use your internet to locate you.

Comment: You mean to say by using the same above mentioned methods i can update user location using GPS??

Answer (score 3):

GPS doesn't need data exchange using internet, but it has basically 2 disadvantages:

1. it takes a long time to get position if you haven't used it recently (this is
   due to satellite search)
2. it doesn't work inside buildings or where streets are too small
   between buildings (this happens a lot in Italy)

Another way that it doesn't need data exchange is location based on cell tower, but of course your device should have cellular chip installed.

From your code I see three things that should be fixed as soon as possible.

- Sometimes the first location is cached and it doesn't represent the
  actual location
- It will be better to stop the location manager when you receive a
  valid coordinate, that means: not cached, with an horizontal accuracy   >=0 and with an horizontal accuracy that match your requirements,
- The delegate methods to get location is deprecated (depending on your
  deployment target). Here is a little snippet for the first two
  points:

  ```
  -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

      CLLocation * newLocation = [locations lastObject];
      if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0) {
          return;
      }
      NSTimeInterval interval = [newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
      if (abs(interval)>20) {
          return;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Ohke i can fix that. But if i don't have an internet connection then it would straight away call - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error . What to do in that situation?