# iOS : Check the Coordinate using GPS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, gps

I want to bring my location coordinates only by using GPS and not with triangulation of cellular data,wifi network if they both are turned on.How to do this in iOS7?

Please help me on that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269921/updating-user-location-using-iphone-gps-without-internet

Comment: Hello Rayz: Not useful for me, because I need the location from GPS only, But don't know How can detect this. Means when GPS is on , or WiFi is on , data will be coming from GPS or others. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Check horizontal accuracy of Location:
If it is < 30m then it is GPS

2) Check Location.course (maybe called heading) and speed: If valid it came from GPS, Only GPS delivers course and speed

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it might be what you are looking for

http://www.vellios.com/2010/08/16/core-location-gps-tutorial/